# How do I enter a new line in a cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: keyboard, google-drive, google-sheets

When accessing a spreadsheet in Google Drive on a computer with a keyboard, I can enter a new line in a single cell by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

My keyboard on my Android doesn't even have an <kbd>alt</kbd> key.

How do I enter a new line on my Android device?

For a keyboard on my Android, I'm currently using Swype, but I am assuming, and hoping, there is some kind of general approach that is not specific to a particular keyboard.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no "general approach" for that. You might want to take a look into my list on [Keyboards & Input Methods](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_keyboards), which holds several candidates like [Hackers Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) which support such "additional keys".

Comment: Idea #1 to try: create a "reference document" with a single cell where you put in the "new line" character in the cell on a PC and then use copy and paste on your Android device.  Idea #2: does Google sheets support macros?

Comment: PERFECT ANSWER, RIGHT HERE GUYS:


http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25359/how-does-one-add-a-new-line-in-a-cell-in-a-google-spreadsheet

Comment: @user110230, that answer only applies to desktop computers, not to Android phones.

Answer (score 32):

Easiest way:  add an extra letter at the end of the line. Select that letter. Hit enter. The letter will be replaced with a new line.

Comment: This is the only right answer

Comment: It has some important caveats: 1) It doesn't work with physical (bluetooth) keyboards, at leasst for me 2) it really needs to be a *letter*.  If you select a space, it doesn't work.

Comment: It works with Google Pinyin, but does not work with Google Japanese keyboard

Comment: It doesn't work in the Google Spreadsheet app (didn't try on the webapp)

Answer (score 5):

The function `CHAR(10)` will return a Line Feed.

Combining with functions like `CONCATENATE()` or `&` will give a new line. Example:

```
=CONCATENATE("First line"; CHAR(10); "Second line")
="First line"&CHAR(10)&"Second line"
```

Answer (score 4):

The only way that I found so far is through the clipboard.

Using a source document with a line break, with some effort you could succeed in selecting just the line break, and then copy/paste it.

Even easier is to use an app such as "Unicode Pad" or "Unicode CharMap", both of which will find and then copy/paste any character. You'll need to look for LF, LINE FEED or U+000A.
Note that you won't "see" the character after you select it, it shows as a space for obvious reasons.
This still isn't as convenient as I would like it to be, but at least I found it to work reliably.

Answer (score 3):

Mark the cell in which you want to have new lines.

At the top menu click the "A" next to the redo button.

[image: Select submenu]

in the lower screen section a modal pops up. There hit the tab "CELL".

Than activate "Wrap Text".

[image: Cell + Wrap Text]

Now this cell will do line-breaks on long text.

Comment: Wrapping is not the same as an inserted line break.

Comment: wbogacz is correct that this isn't a line break, but this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The highlight a throw-away character and hit enter trick, as well as the type everything into a text editor, then copy/paste it into the Google Sheets cell, both only work on Android devices. I have a Google Spreadsheet that I'm sharing with a client who has an iPhone, and she needs to be able to enter multiple lines within a cell. So I came up with just a little Google Apps Script code to do it on her iPhone (can be entered into the drop-down menu of the Google Spreadsheet, Tools >> Script editor):

```
function onEdit(e) {
    e.range.setValue(e.value.replace(/\\\\/g, '&#92;&#92;').replace(/ *\\n */g, '\n').replace(/&#92;/g, '\\'));
}
```

Basically, that creates a function (that is automatically linked to a Google Sheets trigger), and will run every time a cell is edited. It simply replaces all of the "\n" characters in your text with a line-break. Make sure that's a backslash, and not a normal slash. For programmers, the "\n" is a special character that represents a carriage return within a string. The only possible exception where an accidental line-break might happen would be when trying to input a Windows path into a cell such as "C:\Users\John\Documents\news". So double-backslashes is the common workaround for Windows paths among programmers. So one could enter "C:\Users\John\Documents\news" or even just simply "C:\Users\John\Documents\news" (since \n is really the only string we're replacing at this point).

It's also possible to change the replacement characters, in case anyone is more familiar with HTML:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    e.range.setValue(e.value.replace(/ *<br *\/*> */ig, '\n'));
}
```

Since "`<br>`" is much more deliberate (people don't accidentally type that in unless they want a line-break), it makes for a simpler replace function, since we don't have to do an escape for double-backslashes. But personally, typing in the angled brackets from an Android touchscreen keyboard are a bit inconvenient to do so twice for every line-break...

-Ted

Comment: Nice, I think this is by far the most convenient way! I used myself just " lb " (as in line break) to be the value to be replaced with the newline so I can just write "line 1 lb line 2" and don't even need to go to special characters :)

Answer (score 1):

The following trick worked for me:
Ctrl + Enter

Comment: Mind to explain where Android devices have the `Ctrl` key? Note this site is about Android, not Desktop.

Comment: I assume (but haven't tested) that this might work on 3rd-party keyboard apps that have Ctrl key like Hacker's Keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded by pressing several times Enter when typing a message, select all, copy it and paste it into a cell in a sheet.

Answer (score -2):

Just select a line and press + (top right on the tool bar), you'll be offered to insert a row above or below or a link.

Comment: Note that the OP wants to insert a new line *inside a cell*, or probably should be called as line break instead... but not a new row.